# fastlane: [!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - Package not found: com.example.todo

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane

I am using React-native for my app. I have named my name `reactamplify`. I want to deploy my app to Google play-store. For automation deployment I am using first time `fastlane`. I found this [documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_play_store/), follow the steps and give API [grant access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdKmr.png). In my React native app, I navigate to `android` folder then run this  command `fastlane init`. Give `json_key_file` path my downloaded auth json file. But I got confused about package name. I search my app name in vscode `com.reactamplify` replace them into `com.example.todo`. Then run android folder `fastlane supply init`, I am getting this error: `[!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - Package not found: com.example.todo.` I really don't know how to fix it :(. Really lost TBH.

When I run `fastlane supply`. I got this image

[image]

**PS: It would be awesome if someone gives me example with images**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found the reason. I need to upload at least one build to google Play store app manually. That’s why I got package name error.

Comment: I am getting the same exact error message when doing `expo upload:android`. What do you mean by "upload at least one build"? That's exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: Do you have expo account? If yes, then run this command `expo build:android `. It will build apk in your expo account. Then you will download `apk` file to your laptop/desktop. Then go to https://play.google.com/console/developers website and upload your apk in production https://res.cloudinary.com/drewzxzgc/image/upload/v1635404261/wuqgoik92dm2nvrqok12.png

Comment: Many thanks. I did `expo build:android`, then I run `expo upload:android`, I choose to use the latest build in the cloud (so no need to download `aap`), I have JSON keys downloaded and then I run `expo upload:android` and it fails. There are commands `expo publish:...`, which I never run because I don't understand what it is for. So you mean I have to do one upload manually, after that I will be able to that from command line?

Comment: Yes. You have to upload manually. I follow this setup: https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/ and tutorial: https://dev.to/jeiman/automating-mobile-application-deployments-using-fastlane-and-ci-cd-tools-2iae. I understand it's confusing at the beginning.

Comment: This is also another important steps you have to do it. https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

otherwise you cannot manually upload your apk build in play-store. it will shows error in play-store

Comment: Reads these three links carefully and make sure you read every line . Sometimes I am so impatient to read all and try to make things faster, And that cause me times.

Comment: I see you edited your answer. "Manually" is the key word, now it makes sense. Expo is switching from `expo build` to `eas` tool. I have the patience to read all, but they are not explaining how to use old tools, and I don't want to use `eas`, which is in preview stage and paid if you want to submit to store. I think I should learn fastlane instead of expo tools.

Comment: eas tool? What is eas tool.

Comment: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli

Comment: Yeah this happens with eas too, it's actually documented: https://docs.expo.dev/submit/android/#manually-uploading-your-app-for-the-first

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I deleted the `fastlane` folder and then ran the following again:

```
fastlane supply init
```

Answer (score -1):

For me i found that google play ignore the "com." in the package name! So when submitting a new release make sure to remove "com." from your package string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doing this I get a different error: `Google Api Error: Invalid request - Package not found:`